# WrapperQueryBuilder - aggs query throwing Query Malformed exception

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I have a Json query string:
 `"\"query\":{\"match_all\": {}},\"aggs\":{\"avg1\":{\"avg\":{\"field\":\"age\"} } }";`

When query is executed via `Jest Client`, aggregation values are available.

But when this query is converted into a Query Builder (`WrapperQueryBuilder`) object, getting the following exception.

```
; nested: QueryParsingException[[st1index] [_na] query malformed, must start with start_object]; }{[ixJ-6RHNR5C6fC7HfJHqaw][st1index][4]: SearchParseException[[st1index][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{
  "query" : {
    "wrapper" : {
      "query" : "InF1ZXJ5Ijp7Im1hdGNoX2FsbCI6IHt9fSwiYWdncyI6eyJhdmcxIjp7ImF2ZyI6eyJmaWVsZCI6ImFnZSJ9IH0gfQ=="
    }
  }
}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[st1index] [_na] query malformed, must start with start_object]; }]
```

How do i fix this?

Edit 1: Code analysis:
Code analysis details added:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
try{
    //Jest client building
            JestClientFactory factory = new JestClientFactory();
            HttpClientConfig config = new HttpClientConfig.
                    Builder("http://localhost:9201")
                    .connTimeout(10000)
                    .readTimeout(10000)
                    .multiThreaded(true).build();

            factory.setHttpClientConfig(config);
            JestClient jestClient = factory.getObject();

            String query ="{\"query\":{\"match_all\": {}},\"aggs\":{\"avg1\":{\"avg\":{\"field\":\"age\"} } }}";
             String query2 ="{\"match_all\": {}},\"aggs\":{\"avg1\":{\"avg\":{\"field\":\"age\"} } }}";

            WrapperQueryBuilder wrapQB = new WrapperQueryBuilder(query2);
            SearchSourceBuilder ssb = new SearchSourceBuilder();
            ssb.query(wrapQB);

//working code commented
            //   Search.Builder searchBuilder = new Search.Builder(query).addIndex("st1index").addType("st1type");

//code which needs to be fixed
            Search.Builder searchBuilder = new 
Search.Builder(ssb.toString()).addIndex("st1index").addType("st1type");
            SearchResult result = jestClient.execute(searchBuilder.build());
            System.out.println(result.getJsonString());
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("inside exception block");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

with String query and with commented SearchSourceBuilder, aggs results are displayed. But by using WrapperQueryBuilder , unable to retrieve aggs results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, you're simply missing enclosing braces:

```
"{\"query\":{\"match_all\": {}},\"aggs\":{\"avg1\":{\"avg\":{\"field\":\"age\"}}}}";
 ^                                                                               ^
 |                                                                               |
this one...                                                         ...and this one
```

**UPDATE**

In the `WrapperQueryBuilder`, you can only pass the content of the `query` part, and not the `aggregations` part. You need to add the aggregation part directly on the `SearchSourceBuilder`like this:

```
SearchSourceBuilder ssb = new SearchSourceBuilder();

// add the query part
String query ="{\"match_all\": {}}";
WrapperQueryBuilder wrapQB = new WrapperQueryBuilder(query);
ssb.query(wrapQB);

// add the aggregation part
AvgBuilder avgAgg = AggregationBuilders.avg("avg1").field("age");
ssb.aggregation(avgAgg);
```

Comment: Modified the query and now I am not getting any exception. However, aggs data is still empty. When I run via Head plugin, I am getting the results - any thing i am missing -@Val

Comment: to add more, I am using WrapperQueryBuilder. so query String I am passing is {\"match_all\": {},\"aggs\":{\"avg1\":{\"avg\":{\"field\":\"age\"} } }}. I need to skip "query" since it would be added by wrapper. I need to know how to make it work from here.

Comment: Code analysis details added:

Comment: Oh, indeed, you cannot add `aggs` inside `WrapperQueryBuilder`, since it's only for the `query` part. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Invoking entire query String via any client (JEST) works fine. I do not wish to use AggregationBuilder since all the queries are dynamic and I want to pass it as JSON query string only.  Also my requirement forces me to use QueryBuilder stuff. Is there any way to pass query + aggs as JSON string to QueryBuilder and still get aggs result? - @Val

Comment: Is there any documentation to support the fact that aggregation in JSON string is not supported via TCP based java Client? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see you've created a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34451988/aggregations-in-java-client-through-json-query-without-aggregationbuilder) for this so I'll answer there.