# Aggregations in Java client through JSON query - without AggregationBuilder

Tags: elasticsearch, tcp

I am able to implement `aggregation` functionality via `JSON` query in HTTP based `JEST` client but not in `TCP` based Java client.

Through `JEST` client (HTTP REST based) it is possible to implement aggregation through query String. 
**JEST sample code:**

```
        JestClientFactory factory = new JestClientFactory();
        HttpClientConfig httpClientConfig = new HttpClientConfig
                                    .Builder("http://localhost:9201")
                                    .build();
        factory.setHttpClientConfig(httpClientConfig);
        JestClient client = factory.getObject();

        String queryString ="{\"query\":{\"match_all\": {}},\"aggs\":{\"avg1\":{\"avg\":{\"field\":\"age\"} } }}";

        Search.Builder searchBuilder = new Search.Builder(queryString)
.addIndex("st1index")
    .addType("st1type");  

        SearchResult response = client.execute(searchBuilder.build());

        System.out.println(response.getJsonString());

        client.shutdownClient();
```

Printing response of JEST client shows aggregation results.

---

Using `TCP client` in `elasticsearch`, `aggregation` is possible through `AggregationBuilder`.

When I tried to implement JSON query in  `TCP`, it did not return aggregation results.

Is there any reason why TCP do not support aggregation through query string but supports with adding aggregation options?

**TCP Java client sample code:**

**Edited**
Removed `WrapperQueryBuilder` surrounding the queryString.

```
Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
                .put("cluster.name", "javaEscluster")
                .put("node.name", "arivu").build();
Client client = new TransportClient(settings)
     .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", 9303));

String queryString ="{\"match_all\": {},\"aggs\":{\"avg1\":{\"avg\":{\"field\":\"age\"} } }}";

SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("st1index").setTypes("st1type").setQuery(queryString).execute().actionGet();

System.out.println("Getresponse-->" +"Index-->"+ response.toString());

//closing node
client.close();
System.out.println("completed");
```

This code retrieves only search results and empty aggregation result data.

**Edited:**

Any reference material which explains the reason would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the main documentation of the [`WrapperQueryBuilder`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/37d762914623c830714c942b95e11d728262b115/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/query/WrapperQueryBuilder.java) class, it is stated:

> A Query builder which allows building a query given JSON string or binary data provided as input. This is useful when you want to use the Java Builder API but still have JSON query strings at hand that you want to combine with other query builders.

The keyword in here is the word **query**, i.e. the part named `query` in the request you send to the ES `_search` endpoint, i.e.:

```
{
    "sort": {
       ...          <--- whatever sorting definition you have goes here
    },
    "_source": {
       ...          <--- whatever source definition you have goes here
    },
    "query": {
       ...          <--- this is the content you can use with WrapperQueryBuilder
    },
    "aggs": {
       ...          <--- whatever aggs definition you have goes here
    }
}
```

`WrapperQueryBuilder` will only ever consider whatever you can fit inside that `query` section, so as you can see that doesn't include aggregations, which are in another top-level section of the request.

So, in the JSON query string you give, only the `match_all` will be considered, because that's the only valid token that is allowed to appear in the `query` section, the `aggs:{...}` part is not.

```
"{\"match_all\": {},\"aggs\":{\"avg1\":{\"avg\":{\"field\":\"age\"} } }}"
     ^                 ^
     |                 |
this is valid        this is NOT valid
```

Comment: Thank you.. But I had to update the code without WrapperQueryBuilder but misplaced with this one. sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: your suggestions on this question without usage of WrapperQueryBuilder please.

Comment: There is simply no way to build aggregations from a string the same way you can do for the query part.

Comment: --@Val, to add more details, in our application we use TCP and HTTP based client interchangeably. since JEST client supports query based aggregation whereas TCP Java client does not.  So, I am in need of any documented reference material to show that TCP do not support this.

Comment: It's not a question of TCP vs HTTP, it's simply the Elasticsearch Java API that doesn't support this. Your HTTP client is Jest-based which is a different project that provides a different Java API.

Comment: You can have a look at [SearchRequestBuilder](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/search/SearchRequestBuilder.java#L367) which is the API that you use to create searches using the Elasticsearch API.